# HighCharts numericSymbols in French and German

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In HighCharts it is possible to change the language used for the date axis of charts so that dates appear in different languages (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#lang).  One of the properties on this that can be changed is `numericSymbols` which has a value of `['k', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P', 'E']`.

Does anyone know what the French and German versions of this would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just the same in French and German, that's why it's called the [International System of Units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units#Prefixes).

By the way, it derives from the [Metric system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_system), which was invented in France, so no wonder the prefixes are the same.